# How to set ThemeMode in splash screen using value stored in sqflite FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, splash-screen, sqflite

I have a Flutter Application where an [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) database stored the user preference of ThemeMode (viz Dark, Light and System). I have created a splash screen using [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) which supports dark mode too. 
The Problem is this that I want the splash screen to follow the users stored value for theme mode. Currently, the code I am using is as follows:

```
class MyRoot extends StatefulWidget {
  // const MyRoot({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static ValueNotifier<ThemeMode> themeNotifier = ValueNotifier(ThemeMode.system);

  @override
  State<MyRoot> createState() => _MyRootState();
}


class _MyRootState extends State<MyRoot> {
  DatabaseHelper? databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.dhInstance;
  ThemeMode? tmSaved;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async => await loadData());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //to prevent auto rotation of the app
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ThemeMode>(
      valueListenable: MyRoot.themeNotifier,
      builder: (_, ThemeMode currentMode, __) {
        return Sizer(
          builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
            return MaterialApp(
              title: 'My Application',
              theme: themeLight, //dart file for theme
              darkTheme: themeDark, //dart file for theme
              themeMode: tmSaved ?? currentMode,
              initialRoute: // my initial root
              routes: {
                // my routes
                .
                .
                .
                // my routes
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> loadData() async {
    if (databaseHelper != null) {
      ThemeMode? themeMode= await databaseHelper?.selectStoredTheme(); // function retrieving sqflite stored value and returning ThemeMode value
      if (themeMode != null) {
         MyRoot.themeNotifier.value = themeMode;
         return;
      }
    }
    MyRoot.themeNotifier.value = ThemeMode.system;
  }
}
```

Currently, this shows a light theme splash screen loading, then converts it into dark with a visible flicker. 
`ValueListenableBuilder<ThemeMode>(...` is to enable real time theme change from settings page in my app which working as intended (taken from [A Goodman's article: "Flutter: 2 Ways to Make a Dark/Light Mode Toggle"](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-ways-to-make-a-dark-light-mode-toggle/#Using_Self-Written_Code).

`main.dart` has the below code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyRoot());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the setting from `sqflite` in `main()` before `runApp`? If you can manage to do so, you should be able to pass the setting as argument to `MyRoot` and then the widgets would be loaded from the start with the correct theme. I'm speaking in theory, I can't test what I'm suggesting right now.

Something like:

```
void main() async {
  ThemeMode? themeMode= await databaseHelper?.selectStoredTheme(); // function retrieving sqflite stored value and returning ThemeMode value
  runApp(MyRoot(themeMode));
}

[...]

class MyRoot extends StatefulWidget {
  ThemeMode? themeMode;

  const MyRoot(this.themeMode, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static ValueNotifier<ThemeMode> themeNotifier = ValueNotifier(ThemeMode.system);

  @override
  State<MyRoot> createState() => _MyRootState();
}
```

EDIT

Regarding the nullable value you mentioned in comments, you can change the `main` like this:

```
void main() async {
  ThemeMode? themeMode= await databaseHelper?.selectStoredTheme(); // function retrieving sqflite stored value and returning ThemeMode value
  themeMode ??= ThemeMode.system;
  runApp(MyRoot(themeMode!));
}
```

which makes `themeMode` non-nullable, and so you can change `MyRoot` in this way:

```
class MyRoot extends StatefulWidget {
  ThemeMode themeMode;

  const MyRoot(required this.themeMode, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  [...]
}
```

Regarding the functionality of `ValueNotifier`, I simply thought of `widget.themeMode` as the initial value of your `tmSaved` property in your state, not as a value to be reused in the state logic. Something like this:

```
class _MyRootState extends State<MyRoot> {
  DatabaseHelper? databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.dhInstance;
  late ThemeMode tmSaved;

  @override
  void initState() {
    tmSaved = widget.themeMode;
    super.initState();
  }
  [...]
}
```

so that your widgets would already have the saved value at the first build.

PS the code in this edit, as well as in the original part, isn't meant to be working by simply pasting it. Some things might need adjustments, like adding `final` to `themeMode` in `MyRoot`.

Comment: Didn't work: Firstly, had to declare like this `final ThemeMode? themeMode;`,<br /> secondly, gives `null` means possibly the query failed before `runApp`. <br /> Also, if I am using `themeMode: widget.themeMode ?? currentMode,`, I lose the immediate theme change from settings which is possible through `ValueNotifier`

Comment: One more thing if you could help with, I am doing this to check the value `Widget build(BuildContext context) {print(widget.themeMode.toString()); ........` this prints `null`  3 times on the console. Can you tell why and how to prevent this?

Comment: I've expanded my answer. Regarding the `null` printing, I'm not even sure that `ThemeMode.toString()` is meant to print anything meaningful. In any case, if it does print `null` and not throw an exception, that means that `themeMode` has a valid value. It simply means that its `toString` prints null. Try testing its value with something more complex, like `if (themeMode == ThemeMode.dark) print('dark');`

Comment: Hi, plz don't get frustrated, I simply told you for knowledge sake that I had to make it `final`, and its obvious that my code in question isn't the exact code, and your code in answer too isn't. So thanks for the edit but as I told, the database query itself is returning null (as if table doesn't exist) when queried in `main()` , and returns valid/stored value when I check the same in next page, in `MyRoot` (i.e. when the app has started running) & I haven't written `ThemeMode.toString()`, I wrote `widget.themeMode.toString()` which is `null`. One Liner, database calls not working in `main()`

Comment: Mhm, that's strange. I remember using `sqflite` in `main` in at least one project, even though I could not find which one right now. 
In any case, sorting through my files made me remember something: to use plugins before `runApp`, you must call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` in the first lines of code. In the cookbook example (see [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite)) it is shown how to use a `sqflite` instance in `main`

Comment: Hi, tried this: in `main() async`, `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); runApp(MyRoot(themeMode));` and in `MyRoot` `...themeMode: widget.themeMode ?? currentMode,...`, the problem, now `ValueListenableBuilder` has stopped listening. i.e. the line `MyRoot.themeNotifier.value = ThemeMode.any` isn't working anymore and theme change in real time is not happening. However, there is still a flicker at the start, from the original splash (light as per system) to my home splash (dark as per user choice)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with `ValueListenableBuilder` or the likes, so I won't try to give you advice on that. In any case, I noticed that in the last comment there's still `theme.mode: widget.themeMode ?? currentMode`, which still gives priority to the `final` property of the widget and not to the editable one of the state. Maybe switching the sides of the `??` operator can help

Answer (score 0):

Make your splashscreen. A main widget which get data from sqlflite
And make splashscreen widget go to the your home widget with remove it using navigation pop-up

for example :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
                                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                                title: 'ToDo',
                                color: // color of background
                                theme: // theme  light  ,
                                darkTheme: // darktheme 
                                themeMode:  // choose default theme light - dark - system
                                home:  Splashscreen(),// here create an your own widget of splash screen contains futurebuilder to fecth data and return the mainWidget ( home screen for example)
                                                     

                              );
  }
}

class Splashscreen extends StatelessWidget {

  Future<bool> getData()async{
    // get info  
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context,snapshot){
           // if you want test snapshot 
            //like this 

             if(snapshot.hasData) {

              return Home();
            

          } else {
            return Container(color: /* background color as same as theme's color  */);

          }
            
         
        }

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share a bit details on how to as in the question, splash screen already exists. Thanks.

Comment: check a my code

Comment: Point is, by the time Future is build, I want to know the stored theme in sqflite, so that I can show appropriate splash/initial loading screen.

Comment: i use provider package check my code ToDoList :
https://github.com/EngrTAHAR-Noureddine/ToDoList.git